# How can I use audio slices as samples?

Tags: software, electronic-music, cubase

I'm trying to remix a song, and I've cut an audio event (referencing its own clip) into slices. Is there a way to use these slices to make a rhythmic beat, as if each slice were a drum pad (other than manually copying and pasting events)?

Comment: Well, yes - this is one of the core functions of a DAW, or various other tools which let you add repeats etc.

Comment: @DrMayhem That's not what I meant; rather than duplicating each syllable every time I wanted to use it again, I'd use them as...er...samples.

Comment: I was hoping that was what you meant:-) Yes, why not just use them as samples :-)

Comment: @DrMayhem Maybe he doesn't know how to use them as samples. That's kinda his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! While using Groove Agent SE, you can just drag the audio parts or slices you want onto the pad you want them on; then you can just "Create Drum Map From Instrument" and then edit the drum part in the drum editor thing like normal.